# How to set the asp.net website screen compatible to any screen resolution

Tags: asp.net

I have a asp.net website. I need to use it in various computers at various screen resolution. How can I make my screen size compactible with various screen resolution.pls give a sln, this is my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
</head>
<body>


    <form id="form1" runat="server">

    <div style="width: 100%; height: 100%">


 <br />

           <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" BackColor="#5E4AB5" Text="ITEM REPORT"
                Width="200px" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" onclick="Button1_Click" />

            <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" BackColor="#5E4AB5" Text="INVOICE"
                Width="200px" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />

            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" ForeColor="#3399FF" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
        <br />

        <br />
        <br />
    <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" Height="115px"
            ImageUrl="~/images/logo.png" Width="250px" />
        <br />
     <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" BackColor="#FF6600" Font-Bold="True"
            Font-Size="X-Large" ForeColor="#990000"
            Text=" PRODUCT MANAGEMENT SYSTEM- HOME"></asp:Label>

        <br />
      <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" Height="36px"
            ImageUrl="~/images/newlogo.jpg" PostBackUrl="https://www.somatco.com"
            Width="34px" />


    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you mean you want the website to be responsive?

Comment: You can use something like Bootstrap.js. It will scale your website for any device from mobile to pc. For more details http://getbootstrap.com/

Comment: My asp.net website is compatible with my screen resolution 1920* 1080, but when I change the screen resolution it totally changed. all arrangements of site, button position are changed. So how can I fix this . How can I use my site in various screen resolution with no alignment change.